# java streams - how to filter list of list based on the value in the inner list

Tags: java-stream

I got an input List<list < Health>> e.g.

```
[[Health{key='day', value='mon'}, Health{key='bp', value='ok'}, Health{key='temp', value='ok'}],
[Health{key='day', value='tues'}, Health{key='bp', value='notok'}, Health{key='temp', value='ok'}]
...]
```

I want to filter the input such that, output should be a List<list < Health >> whose 'bp'is 'notok' && 'temp' is 'ok'.

```
e.g output should be 
[[Health{key='day', value='tues'}, Health{key='bp', value='notok'}, Health{key='temp', value='ok'}]]
```

I have taken [filter inner and outer list in java using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884620/filter-inner-and-outer-list-in-java-using-streams) as reference but not sure how to filter on the Health which is a dict.

Comment: What communication standard is that?  (I thought it was JSON at first.)

Comment: input.stream().forEach(healths -> {healths.stream().filter(health.getValue('bp').contains('notok')).collect(Collectors.toList())})

Comment: @RevathyMourouguessane Looks like his code would not compile (for instance pay attention to predicate in the filter). And the snippet seem to be incomplete. It's also not very clear what should the end result. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74405164/edit) the question: **1.** Add the complete version of code, **fix the bugs** which you're able to fix, **2.** Add `Health` class. **3.** Provide the **compilation error**.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a pair instead of Health but should look something like this:

```
List<List<Pair<String,String>>> healthList = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Pair<String,String>>> filterdList = healthList.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.stream()
                .anyMatch(l -> l.getKey().equals("bp") && l.getValue().equals("notOk")))
        .filter(m -> m.stream()
                .anyMatch(l -> l.getKey().equals("temp") && l.getValue().equals("ok")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```